# How to make a scoring system in c# (Converting int to string and string to bool in c#)

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a scoring system where if the user inputs 1 into the text box it outputs 4 into the listbox and so on. i've tried using Convert.Int32 and .ToString and bool.Parse Nothing has worked so far.

```
private void PlaceBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   BadForm.place = Convert.ToInt32(points);
   points = Convert.ToInt32(PlaceBox.Text);

   bool.Parse(PlaceBox.Text = 1.ToString());


   if (PlaceBox.Text = 1.ToString())
   {
      PlaceBox.Text = 4;
   } 
   else if (PlaceBox.Text = 2)
   {
      PlaceBox.Text = 3;
   }
   else if (PlaceBox.Text = 3)
   {
      PlaceBox.Text = 2;
   }
   else if (PlaceBox.Text = 4)
   {
      PlaceBox.Text = 1;
   }                
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
   }            
}
```

Thats the code it's very basic but and that's just for one form

Comment: First, you probably want to use `==` to compare values. Second, you may just want to use string literals instead of numbers with `ToString()`. So something like `if (PlaceBox.Text == "1") { PlaceBox.Text = "4"; }`

Comment: A single `=` will assign a value. Use `==` to compare values; it produces a boolean value, and then you probably no longer will need the attempt at using `bool.Parse()`.